# Specializing a Template Alias Inside a Template

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I have a matrix class as follows.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N> 
class Matrix
{
  std::array<std::array<T, N>, M> data_;
};
```

I want to create a row alias inside this matrix for ease similar to

```
template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N> 
class Matrix
{
  template<>
  using row = std::array<T, N>;

  std::array<row, M> data_;
};
```

My compiler tells me that this alias is still unspecialized though. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles for me:

```
#include <array>

template <typename T, std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class Matrix
{
    using row = std::array<T, N>;

    std::array<row, M> data_;
};
```

This is not really specialization, just an ordinary `using` alias definition.